# Unsupported operand type(s) for +:'Decimal' and 'Decimal'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have some python code in a Django project that used to be working. The server that was hosting the project was lost and I had to copy the code over to a new server. Now, I am getting an error that seems to make no sense.

I have the following in one of my python files:

```
from decimal import Decimal
...
obj.hours = obj.hours + Decimal('2.5')
```

where `obj.hours` is a `Decimal` object which I have verified by debugging and seeing that the `obj.hours = Decimal('0')`. I have made no changes to the page that the code was on, like I said, the only change was moving the code to a different server. I don't understand why this used to be working and no longer is, and I don't understand why it doesn't work in the first place because I am adding two Decimals.

Comment: Are you sure that they're the same `Decimal`? Print the `__module__` attribute of each.

Comment: The only reference I can find is [ridiculously old](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/CRqmwIj2wJA), but maybe related?

Comment: I ended fixing the issuing by doing this: `Decimal(str(float(semreqs.escortHours) - 2.5))`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use two Decimal classes at the same time and one of them is not supporting '+'. Maybe somewhere have been created a Decimal class and it overwritten original one. See [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/685196-typeerror-unsupported-operand-type-s-decimal-decimal-why). I don't know how changing a server caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a name collision issue. Try to change your import statement

```
import decimal
...
obj.hours = obj.hours + decimal.Decimal('2.5')
```